# Plotnine graphing melted dataframe as 2 separate lines

Tags: python, visualization, plotnine

I am trying to graph a melted dataframe, as shown here:

```
    SleepDay                category            value
0   4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM   TotalMinutesAsleep  750
1   4/13/2016 12:00:00 AM   TotalMinutesAsleep  398
2   4/15/2016 12:00:00 AM   TotalMinutesAsleep  475
3   4/26/2016 12:00:00 AM   TotalMinutesAsleep  296
4   4/28/2016 12:00:00 AM   TotalMinutesAsleep  166
5   4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM   TotalTimeInBed      775
6   4/13/2016 12:00:00 AM   TotalTimeInBed      422
7   4/15/2016 12:00:00 AM   TotalTimeInBed      499
8   4/26/2016 12:00:00 AM   TotalTimeInBed      315
9   4/28/2016 12:00:00 AM   TotalTimeInBed      178
```

This is my code so far:

```
ggplot(long_data, aes(x='SleepDay', y='value', color = "category")) +\
    geom_line(aes(group = 1)) +\
    theme(axis_text_x=element_text(rotation=75, hjust=1))
```

Graphing it gives me the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq29T.png

I have no clue how to separate the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aes(group=1)` says all the rows in the data are assigned to group `1`. This overrides the global grouping that depends on the `category`, so all the points fall on the same line!

The solution is to remove `group=1`.

Comment: When I do that, it causes the graph to just not show up and the following error:geom_path.py:111: PlotnineWarning: geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Comment: Then you have another discrete/categorical column that affects the automatic grouping. Probably the `SleepDay` column! You can either change the type of that column or set `aes(group="category")`.